# Menu/Navbar in Magento

Tags: php, html, css, magento-1.7, menubar

I want to edit the top navbar on Magento so that it's main categories are each a different colour, rather than the present bar which is one colour.  I know how to do this using html/css but not how to tweak it through Magnento.  Has anyone got any pointers please?

Comment: By the way I have the CSS code for this, I am just unclear on how to interject the existing php

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a new Category Attribute. We will use this attribute to store the colour code you want to use for each category. You could store a class name to add into the element, or just a colour code that's upto you :)

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/

2) Modify Navigation block to inject the colour/style into the nav when it's rendered.

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()
```

what you need to do here will depend on the version of Magento you are using.